X,Y, Z data. Creating Surface plot and interpolating from surface plot
I am working on data analysis using Pandas.
I have X, Y and Z columns of data in data frame. I want to create a surface plot (with specific grid points) out of it (preferably cubic/spline interpolation) which something looks like as blow.


But my main question is: From this surface how to interpolate for an array of Xi and Yi to get corresponding array of Zi like below:

I have tried "griddata" from scipy but unable to do it with the way I want to interpolate.

"From this surface how to interpolate for an array of Xi and Yi to get corresponding array of Zi like below:" I'm a little confused by this example, as it doesn't show any Zi values.

Never post picture of data. Copy paste and format instead.

You can use matplotlib.plot_surface function for plotting (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_surface.html)
I really don't know how to do this in bokeh, but I found this example: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/branch-3.6/examples/server/app/surface3d, which could be pretty useful.
And you can use scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline
(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline.html) to effectively interpolate:
from scipy.interpolate import SmoothBivariateSpline

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] * 8)
y = np.array(sorted([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] * 8))
z = np.array(
    [i * j for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] 
        for j in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])

spline = SmoothBivariateSpline(x, y, z)

print(spline(3, 3.5))
print(spline(1.5, 8))

Output:
[[10.5]]
[[12.]]


I tried "SmoothBivariateSpline" but  it crashes with message "Windows fatal exception: code 0xc0000374" and many other messages and then final "Restarting kernel...".

How big is your dataset? Looks like it is too big for your machine's memory.

It is not very big, just 258 rows in X, Y and Z. But I would like to point out that some values in Z are NaNs. I am not sure, if that is creating issue.

Can you please show how exactly do you use this function? You can do it in your original post, because comments formatting style was not created for big chunks of code.

How can I upload actual data files (csv) to the question? Is there any way I can do it?

You don't need to show us real csv data, make short example of data:
df_for_plot = pd.DataFrame([
[1, 2, 3],
[11, 22, 33],
.....,
[101, 102, 103]
], columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
